# Trying to the deduce shortcode from a function

Tags: functions, shortcode

I have a theme where the wysiwyg button to insert the shortcodes is not appearing. I am trying to manually type in the shortcode that would output the tabs that I need. I am looking at the function that generates the shortcode to try deduce what that might be. The function is

```
    function display_tabs(){

    var code        = '[tabs ';
    var tab_names   = '';
    var tabs        = '';
    var tab_index   = 0;

    $('.shortcode-dynamic-items').each( function(){

        $(this).children('.shortcode-dynamic-item').each( function(){

            tab_index++;

            tabs += '[tab id=' + tab_index + ']';

            //input loop for extra attrs
            $(this).children('#options-group').find('.attr').each( function(){

                if( $(this).attr('data-attrname') == 'tab_name' ){

                    tab_names += 'tab' + tab_index + '="' + $(this).val() + '" ';
                }

            });

            // if the shortcode has content
            if( $(this).find('#shortcode-content').length > 0 ){

                tabs += $(this).find('#shortcode_content').val();

            }

            tabs += '[/tab]';

        })
    });

    code += tab_names + ']' + tabs + '[/tabs]';

    return code;
}
```

I have tried a few attempts and have the tabs showing on the page but the content of the tabs is not showing and not toggling between them

```
[tabs 1 2 3]
[tab]Content for tab one goes here.[/tab]
[tab]Content for tab two goes here.[/tab]
[tab]Content for tab three goes here.[/tab]
[/tabs]
```

Is it possible to work out exactly what it should be from the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if this would work:

```
[tabs tab1="Tab 1" tab2="Tab 2" tab3="Tab 3"]
    [tab id="1"]Content for tab one goes here.[/tab]
    [tab id="2"]]Content for tab two goes here.[/tab]
    [tab id="3"]]Content for tab three goes here.[/tab]
[/tabs]
```

You should also check if the shortcode definitions exists:

```
add_shortcode( 'tabs', 'some_function_for_tabs' );
add_shortcode( 'tab',  'some_function_for_tab' );
```

Comment: Great that worked! and the shortcode definition does exist. Cheers